# Cant add hash in redis using pydantic model

Tags: python, redis, pydantic

```
class SiteDaoRedis(SiteDaoBase, RedisDaoBase):
    """SiteDaoRedis persists Site models to Redis.
    This class allows persisting (and querying for) Sites in Redis.
    """
    def insert(self, site: Site, **kwargs):
        """Insert a Site into Redis."""
        hash_key = self.key_schema.site_hash_key(site.id)
        site_ids_key = self.key_schema.site_ids_key()
        client = kwargs.get('pipeline', self.redis)
        client.hset(hash_key, mapping=site.dict())
        client.sadd(site_ids_key, site.id)

class Coordinate(BaseModel):
    """A coordinate pair."""
    lng: float
    lat: float


class Site(BaseModel):
    """A solar power installation."""
    id: Optional[UUID] = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    capacity: float
    panels: int
    address: str
    city: str
    state: str
    postal_code: str
    coordinate: Union[Coordinate, None] = None
```

After attempt to insert, **Getting this error:** - **redis.exceptions.DataError: A tuple item must be str, int, float or bytes.**

Comment: `hset` adds key/value pairs to a hash. The values must be "str, int, float or bytes".  Your `Site` model has `coordinate` field which would serialise to a dictionary. Redis does not support nested hashes (i.e. dict within dict). The `id` field may also be a problem, though uuid can be easily converted to string.

Comment: @Anentropic How can I resolve that? I am about problem of nested dict

Comment: If you need to store all the nested fields into Redis then you need to flatten the structure